# DjangoModelPermission with multiple databases

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mezzanine

I have 2 databases.  One containing the AUTH that's also extended in the following models.py -

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class FileIndex(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    filetype = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    vendorid = models.IntegerField()
    vendorname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    tablename = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'file_index'
        verbose_name = 'File/Vendor Index'
        verbose_name_plural = 'File/Vendor Indicies'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename

class UserFile(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    fileid = models.ForeignKey(FileIndex)
    grant_date = models.DateTimeField()
    revoke_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_files'
        verbose_name = 'User File Matrix'
        verbose_name_plural = 'User File Matricies'
```

the 'tablename' field in FileIndex references a Table Name in another database referenced in a separate App.  My current test view I'm using is follows in my views.py

```
class File_List(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = cdx_composites_csv
    serializer_class = cdx_compositesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases for
        the user as determined by the username portion of the URL.
        """
        filename = self.request.GET.get('filename')
        model = get_model('markit', filename)
        filedate = self.request.GET.get('filedate')
        queryset = model.objects.using('markitdb').filter(Date__contains=filedate)
        return queryset
```

If I'm not logged in it works fine and gives "not authorized" but regardless of if I've set view permissions on the table or not my user can still execute the view.

Model is listed before the function or else it will complain about the model not being there.  I want to figure that out later.  First I'm trying to understand why my view is still executing even if the user does not have group permission to view the Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've attacked this by doing the following in my view -

class ExampleView(APIView):
    model = cdx_composites_csv
    serializer_class = cdx_compositesSerializer

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    if UserFile.objects.filter(fileid_id=1, userid_id=2).exists():
        content = {
            'status': 'Request Successful.'
        }
        return Response(content)
    else:
        content = {
            'status': 'Request Failed.'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Essentially after authentication it's doing a query against the UserFile to validate the User and the file exists and if it does then I can write it to do the queryset or not.